# How can I change the opacity of a button in a if statement in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm making and app and I'm in the register/login, I would like to do something similar as instagram does when the email/username or password are empty or the password does not have enough character (8 or more) the button opacity is reduced and when all is correct is 100%, as I'm starting in kotlin and I don't have any knowledge in java I don't know if this is possible

```
if(email.isEmpty()  ||  password.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "please enter text in email/password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
```

what I'm trying to achieve is that in the if statement when else, opacity of button 50%, when if correct opacity of button 100%

the button is located in activity_register and the button id is  registrar_button_register and the

in the if statement also I don´t know how to add that until the password has 8 or more characters the if statement is not completed

could it be done? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the opacity for a `View`, change it's alpha value.

```
registrar_button_register.alpha = 0.5f
```

You could even animate the opacity change using `animate()`

```
registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(0.5f).setDuration(200)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```js
if (your condition) {
    yourButton.setAlpha(1f);
} else {
    yourButton.setAlpha(0.5f);
}
```